# how to copy specific files in linux?

Tags: regex, linux

I am trying to copy some of the files in a source directory to destination directory. The source directory contains following files.

source directory path is ~/certificate/

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 ubuntu ubuntu     4096 Oct 16 11:58 apache
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu     5812 Oct 16 11:20 apache.keystore
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu     1079 Oct 16 08:31 csr.txt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu 36626564 Oct 16 10:08 my.war
drwxrwxr-x 2 ubuntu ubuntu     4096 Oct 16 09:39 tomcat
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu     6164 Oct 16 09:31 tomcat.keystore
```

I want to copy all files to ~/certs/ except my.war (certs is the destination directory). I have tried the following command without success. I do not want to move my.war out of the folder even temporarily.

```
cp -r ~/certificate/(?!m)* ~/cert/.
```

Please help me with suitable regular expression or any other tool.

Comment: A general-purpose solution would be handy, but I mean, it's only 5 files. I hope this isn't holding you up. What about `cp a* c* t* ~/cert/`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using [`bash`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html), you can enable the `extglob` option and use:

```
cp -r ~/certificate/!(my.war) ~/certs/
```

Use

```
shopt -s extglob
```

to enable that option.

Here's a link to the [relevant documentation.](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching)

Answer (score 1):

Well, since it's the only file that starts with an 'm', you could do
`cp -r ~/certificate/[a-ln-z]* ~/cert`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use "find" command. It find all files in directory, except "my.war" files and execute "cp" command for all found files.

```
find . -type f \( -iname "*" ! -iname "my.war" \) -exec cp {} ./cert/ \;
```

Answer (score 0):

For completeness: a [zsh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/zsh/info) solution. In zsh with the `EXTENDED_GLOB` option set you can do (see [documentation](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Operators)):

```
cp -r ~/certificate/^my.war ~/certs
```

or with `KSH_GLOB` (and [`NO_BARE_GLOB_QUAL`](http://www.zsh.org/mla/users/1999/msg00692.html)) options set you can use the same ksh syntax as in bash:

```
cp -r ~/certificate/!(my.war) ~/certs
```